# Install project in version 0.61 of React Native

Tags: react-native, dependencies, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

We are trying to install a React Native version 0.61 and we get an npm install error.
We have forced this error but later, when installing the project dependencies and forcing them, the version is updated to 0.64.
Does anyone know how I could use 0.61 without getting updated?

PS: Previously I have used 0.61 without forcing the dependencies but when I extract the app I find a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have ^ before react-native package in the package JSON

```
"react-native": "^0.64.2",
```

remove "^"

```
"react-native": "0.64.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

please use Stable npm and node version

```
C:\Users\dell>npm --v
6.14.13
```

and

```
C:\Users\dell>node --version
v14.17.3
```

last week I faced many problems due to the latest npm and node versions. finally after downgrading the stale version. it worked for me.